# struts2 and dojo grid

Tags: struts2, dojo

I need an example for populating the dojo grid with the data coming from server. I have struts2 and dojo application in which action class is setting a model variable of type hashmap as the result containing different values that needs to be shown in the form of grid.

Now how can i represent this hashmap in the form of grid data. can you please giving a sample example application which converts the hashmap to json and then uses this json to populate the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Jackson to serialize to JSON.  Does each item in the map represent a row in the grid?  How complex is the data that you are serializing?

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core

If the data structure is simple, then you can probably get away with just using Jackson.
When you want to begin serializing more complex data structures, then you might need to enhance your serialization engine.

I have written some stuff that can do this.  Too much to explain here but you can check out these blog posts and see the code on git hub:

http://swingingcode.blogspot.com/2012/04/json-serialization-engine-part-i.html

http://swingingcode.blogspot.com/2012/04/json-serialization-engine-part-ii.html

https://github.com/cswing/evinceframework/tree/master/web/src/java/com/evinceframework/web/dojo/json

Comment: The data that is complex from server . Where the data should be displayed in the form of tree inside the grid. if click on product family row the related product information gets displayed.. do you have the sample application that serializes and displays in grid

Comment: Use the struts2-json-plugin.  I've put several examples here on SO but the struts2 web site has more information... It is very easy to use.